# Approach to properly archiving and backing up data, preventing data loss and corruption

Tags: file, filesystems, backup, zfs, archiving

I'm looking for a proper way to archive and back up my data. This data consists of photos, video's, documents and more.

There are two main things I'm afraid might cause data loss or corruption, hard drive failure and bit rot.

I'm looking for a strategy that can ensure my data's safety.

I came up with the following. One hard drive which I will regularly use to store and display data. A second hard drive which will serve as an onsite backup of the first one. And a third hard drive which will serve as an offsite backup. I am however not sure if this is sufficient.

I would prefer to use regular drives, and not network attached storage, however if it's better suited I will adapt.

One of the things I read about that might help with bit rot is ZFS. ZFS does not prevent bit rot but can detect data corruption by using checksums. This would allow me to recover a corrupted file from a different drive and copy it to the corrupted one.

I need at least 2TB of storage but I'm considering 4TB to ensure potential future needs.

What would be the best way to safely store my data and prevent data loss and corruption?

Answer (score 0):

For your local system plus local backup, I think a RAID configuration / ZFS makes sense because you’re just trying to handle single-disk failures / bit rot, and having a synchronous copy of the data at all times means you won’t lose the data written since your last backup was taken. With two disks ZFS can do a mirror and handles bit rot well, and if you have more disks you may consider using RAIDZ configurations since they use less storage overall to provide single-disk failure recovery. I would recommend using ZFS here over a general RAID solutions because it has a better user interface.

For your offsite backup, ZFS could make sense too. If you go that route, periodically use `zfs send` to copy a snapshot on the source system to the destination system. Debatably, you should use mirroring or RAIDZ on the backup system to protect against bit rot there too.

That said — there are a lot of products that will do the offsite backup for you automatically, and if you have an offsite backup, the only advantage of having an on-site backup is faster recovery if you lose your primary. Since we’re just talking about personal documents and photos, taking a little while to re-download them doesn’t seem super high stakes. If you use Dropbox / Google Drive / etc. instead, this will all be automatic and have a nice UI and support people to yell at if anything goes wrong. Also, storage at those companies will have much higher failure tolerances because they use huge numbers of disks (allowing stuff like RAIDZ with tens of parity disks and replicated across multiple geographic locations) and they have security experts to make sure that all your data is not stolen by hackers.

The only downsides are cost, and not being as intimately involved in building the system, if that part is fun for you like it is for me :).